# Sonata Admin User - ACL Setup

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Trying to use the ACL mode for Sonata Admin.

From [the docs](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration) I understand that `STAFF` should have `["EDIT","LIST","CREATE"]` permissions

But when I install the ACL mappings:

```
$ php app/console sonata:admin:setup-acl
```

I see that it's doing (among others)

> install ACL for sonata.user.admin.user
>   ...
>   - add role: ROLE_SONATA_USER_ADMIN_USER_STAFF, permissions: ["LIST","CREATE"]
>   ...

And indeed, staff don't get `EDIT` permission when I try a user granted with it.

How can it happen ? How can I give my user this `EDIT` permission ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As nobody answered, let me give you my feedback (based on what I remember)

It seems to be because the default behavior of ACLs for SonataUser grants `STAFF` with `EDIT` access to users they have created (or for which they have [ACE](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html#creer-un-acl-et-ajouter-un-ace))